# Typescript: Create an object type from named tuple

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a function:

```
function myFunc(name: string, age: number){ }
```

To obtain the parameters of a function type in a tuple, I do the following:

```
type TArgs = Parameters<typeof myFunc> // = [name: string, age: number]
```

Now I need to create an object type from this tuple as shown below:

```
type TObj = {
    name: string, 
    age: number
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Not possible to do this

Comment: You can't do this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28259#issuecomment-846078766

Answer (score 1):

As the Typescript Whisperers in the comments have pointed out, You Can't Do This.  I am writing this answer
to help other mortals like me who get confused by the `Parameter<>` utility's [labeled tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) `[name: string, age: number]` output.

At first glance it seems we should be able to reverse engineer key-value pairs from the tooltip output `[name: string, age: number]`.

Alas, no.  After all `[name: string, age: number]` is a labeled version of the tuple `[string, number]`.  Hopes dashed.

> labels don’t require us to name our variables differently when destructuring. They’re purely there for documentation and tooling.

Here are some demonstrations: ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFsBPAMTTAApUoCQAueAZwxi1QHMAaeKd++VMgIAjEDACUDAG44swALAAoJRiIAHBABUAgjHaN4AXngAFWDRAYxjADyqNORIVLkAfPAD0H+Bhw4I2GpMUESMDADa1LQMzKwc3Lz8giJiALpKSl4+IMyMSmB4zPBY2gQ6emHw5fpG8OEARMQAyixs7PXcAAypnt5mjIw5DPYIcFAQEETFBuGxbdzJojDpigWoRSUEAHI4GNWV+7XhnV09WQCiMDA4MAkGIAAeGpggwAya6ggA5ItiX9MCXY8AZYdjUYQQBC+HyfeBfOYcL4qWFbCy6di1MwwCxWGC2EaOZxkdCuY5nbwI9gZZQ06l0xRAA))

```js
const iAmTArgs: TArgs = ["myString", 0] // Passes: type really is [string, number]

const iAmNotTArgs: TArgs = [0, 0] // Error, as expected: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

type NameArg = Parameters<typeof myFunc>[0] // string
```